# Keyboard is hiding Views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have read a lot of questions similar to mine but all are talking about

- `android:windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest
- `fitsSystemWindows` in the views
- Adding Scroll to be a parent view

which are not solving my problem

I am using `Collapsing toolbar layout`, a `Mini Drawer` and My XML that have the problem is on a `Fragment Class`

Here is the XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:context="project.learning.android.afinal.mapcreatelesson.ReportFragment"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsButton
        android:text="{gmd-send} Send"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_dark_header_selection_text"
        app:ico_color="@color/material_drawer_dark_header_selection_text"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Surly it is loading with `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()...` from the main activity into a `FrameLayout`

[image]

As we see my `EditText` and `Button` are in a layout have `gravity=bottom` which when I press the `EditText` the keyboard popup hiding the `EditText` and the Button

Thanks in advance, Please answer a bit explained answer or with a reference to read to understand my layout problem

---

### Update

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="project....mapcreatelesson">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

screenshot for the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply this line to your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

for more details you can go through following link
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: I copied your xml and just putted windowSoftInput mode in my AndroidManifest file and it's working properly.

Comment: for me it's not, is there is any factor affecting this or you need code of other XML or class?

Answer (score 0):

```
[![As you can see the edittext and button is not hidden behind keyboard][1]][1]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

<application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Custom"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iI0M.png
```